# Using Robolectric with android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-testing, robolectric

I have a View that includes an instance of `android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton` in its layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mykwillis.com.mediaroutebutton.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/video_layer_chromecast_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've created the beginning of a basic Robolectric test that does nothing more than build and create the MainActivity:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void loadActivity() {
        MainActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test, I receive the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
```

Digging in deeper, it appears that Robolectric is failing when it tries to load the style information for MediaRouteButton. The relevant stack trace seems to be this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.robolectric.res.AttrData cannot be cast to org.robolectric.res.StyleData at
org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.resolveStyle(ShadowAssetManager.java:617) at 
org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.buildTypedValue(ShadowAssetManager.java:742) at 
org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowAssetManager.java:793) at 
org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResourcesImpl$ShadowThemeImpl.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResourcesImpl.java:177) at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.obtainStyledAttributes(ResourcesImpl.java) at 
android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1440) at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:587) at 
android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getThemeColor(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:169) at 
android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getControllerColor(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:94) at 
android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedContext(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:62) at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.(MediaRouteButton.java) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.1"
    testCompile 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'   // https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1932
}
```

I assume that this means I am out of luck with regard to Robolectric providing a Shadow for `MediaRouteButton` (provided by com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.0), and that I need to create a Shadow for this class myself. I followed the guide at http://robolectric.org/extending/ in an attempt to create a simple shadow that would at least allow my view to load, but to no avail. Here's what I created:

```
@Implements(android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.class)
public class MediaRouteButtonShadow extends ShadowView {
    public void __constructor__(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
    }
}
```

And then I updated my `@Config` statement to be:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, shadows = MediaRouteButtonShadow.class)
```

Unfortunately, I get the same error with this configuration.

Any pointers on how to create a minimal Shadow that will allow the view to load?

Update: a sample application demonstrating the problem is here: https://github.com/mykwillis/android-mediaroutebutton-test

Comment: I am currently working around the problem by dynamically creating my MediaRouteButton conditionally (so I don't do it during Robolectric testing) which is obviously not ideal. I've created an issue with Robolectric here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue, tracked [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2991#issue-216122614), has been resolved using new functionality in [Robolectric version 4.0](http://robolectric.org/blog/2018/10/25/robolectric-4-0/).

Update dependencies and add a `testOptions` section to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0"
}
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

and add this line to gradle.properties:

```
enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true
```

Also make sure you've updated to the latest gradle plugin.